# word for "owners/operators of a pastry shop" and "patissier's wife"

Tags: word-usage, vernacular

What would native speakers call a couple who runs a pastry shop?

In France, the one in the pair that makes the pastries would obviously be called *pâtissier* if a man, and *pâtissière* if a woman, but so would be referred to as their companion who tends store, even though they are not directly involved in the pastry making.

And so, a couple of French *pâtissiers* presenting their occupation well might say something along the lines, "Nous sommes pâtissiers à Bordeaux" (We're '*pâtissiers*' in Bordeaux)" or "Nous avons une pâtisserie à Bordeaux (We run/operate a patisserie in Bordeaux.)"

My second question is, is there a particular word or phrase in English to refer to the patissier's wife who tends store and, as such, doesn't participate directly in the pastry making? Would calling her ***patissière*** fit the bill?

> **pâtissier, pâtissière** *nm, nf*
>
> (*artisan de bouche*) pastry chef *n*; patissier *n*
>
> Le pâtissier fait des gâteaux. *The patissier makes pastries*
>   [WordReference English-French Dictionary © 2016](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/P%C3%A2tissier)

Comment: We don't even have a word for *patisserie*, which is why we use the French word in the first place. So I can't see we're likely to have a special word for the man who owns such a place, let alone his wife (regardless of whether she helps out with the business).

Comment: Around here the guy's called "Otto".  I forget his wife's name.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Then, would "pâtissière" for "pâtissier's wife" be easily perceived by native speakers, considering that the term "pâtissier" in English is apparently used for both a male and female pastry chef? "She's a renowned Scottish pâtissier (pastry chef)" vs. "The pâtissière (pâtissier's wife) was assaulted in her shop as she waited on customers"

Comment: @Elian: I know French, so there's at least a *chance* I'd notice the feminine form. But it would never occur to me that you might mean the "pastry-maker's *wife*" as opposed to someone in that line of business who just happened to be female. Incidentally, if you're going to treat [***patisserie***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/patisserie) and derivatives as "English" words, they shouldn't have accents.

Comment: As it happens, my lodger is a Hilton-trained ***pastry chef***, but I'm not sure I've ever heard him describe himself as a ***patissier***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Indeed, "pastry chef" sounds more to me like one who works in a Michelin-awarded restaurant or the like. I'd suspect "patissier" might be a better fit for an artisan selling their pastries from a shop.

Comment: @HotLicks Does Minnesotan Otto make good pastries?

Comment: The pastry chef's wife runs the business. OR Mr and Mrs [Last Name] own and run a patisserie OR [First Name/Last Name]'s runs the business but her husband is the pastry chef.

Comment: @Elian - At work, news that someone had brought in pastries from Otto's would bring people from two buildings away.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  In Britain, shops where they make pastries on the premises are much rarer than they are in France. And I would have said that there are few such shops which are not also bakeries. So we would normally buy pastries (if not boringly at the Co-Op supermarket) at *the bakery in the High street*. (And thankfully there is at least an English word for one who makes bread). Sadly we have now lost even our bakery (as well as greengrocers) and are reduced to having to buy everything at the supermarket, or else make it/grow it/ or lay it ourselves.

Comment: @WS2 Curiously, "patissier" is a more common word in BrEng than in AmEng https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pastry+baker%2Cpastry+chef%2Cpatissier%2Cpastry+maker&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpastry%20baker%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpastry%20chef%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpatissier%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpastry%20maker%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @HotLicks: His wife's name is also *Otto*. What's good for the pâtissier is good for the pâtissière.

Comment: @Elian But are there many shops making traditional pastries on the premises in America? I mean, apart from the chain formulations like *Dunkin Donuts*. There certainly aren't in Britain. One of the lovely things about staying in a French town always used to be popping out in the early morning to buy a baguette and catching the aroma from the patisserie - and ending up with a bagful for breakfast. .

Comment: @Elian http://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-europe-france-paris-french-pastries-pastries-pastry-french-food-parisian-36902894.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "What do you do?"
>   "We own a pastry shop in Bordeaux."

That said, the word patissier is in use in English-speaking regions (pronounced "pah-tiss-yay"):

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/p%C3%A2tissier

"Pastry chef" can be used as well.

*That* said, pastries are also made by bakers. Here's what Wikipedia has to say on the subject:

> A baker is someone who makes, bakes and sells breads, rolls, biscuits or cookies, and/or crackers using an oven or other concentrated heat source. Cakes and similar foods may also be produced, as the ***traditional boundaries between what is produced by a baker as opposed to a pastry chef have blurred in recent decades***. The place where a baker works is called a bakery.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker

For those of you ... uh ... ye of little faith! Stone Street, New York:

[image]

More:

[image]

Here's what's inside:

[image]

Comment: Use "patissier" in most of the US and you will get weird stares.

Comment: @HotLicks: That would largely depend on the milieu. Pandering to the lowest common denominator is no longer in vogue. ... Well, that's probably wishful thinking on my part, sorry.

Comment: Pandering to the lowest common denominator is the American way!

Comment: @Tom: I beg to differ. We're a country of 300 million-plus souls. To be sure, the philistines constitute a large portion of the population, but there are other people living here who have constitutional rights and personal preferences whose opinions and votes are equally important; never mind that people who actually run things don't give a shit about either group.

Comment: Oops! I touched a nerve!

Comment: @Tom: Not really. But don't awaken the patriot in me.

Comment: I am reasonably educated and understand patissier, but I don't think most Americans would.  Pastry chef is a perfectly good term; a little less "haut" might be pastry maker or pastry baker (just to distinguish to bread baker, although many do both.)

Comment: @StevenLittman: Those who don't know what it means should look it up. It's never too late to learn. Patissier is a perfectly good word that means something; learning what it means is a lot more constructive than sitting back and pretending to understand the President when he says "I take full responsibility for this," which means nothing at all.

Comment: *Patissier* is an unnecessary and pretentious word, borrowed from French, that it's not worth most people's time to learn.  "Pastry chef" is perfectly fine, if one feels the need to specify that occupation at all (few ever would).

Comment: @HotLicks For the simple reason that the Anglophone world simply doesn't have places like you see depicted in some of [these pictures](http://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-europe-france-paris-french-pastries-pastries-pastry-french-food-parisian-36902894.html). We prefer *Krispy Kreme Donuts* out of a machine at the supermarket.

Comment: WS2: Not you too! ...  We do speak English in New York, you know. Here: https://financierpatisserie.com/ I make it a point to stop by each time I'm in the area. Not for the pastries: I'm not a great fan (they're excellent though). It's the coffee and the atmosphere.

Comment: @Ricky--Are you British?  If so, you should understand that we just don't encounter the word patissier in the US.  Patisserie, sometimes.  Usually, the place is pretentious, overpriced, and in a neighborhood that appreciates that combination.  We sure do have lots of pastry shops in the US.  One of my favorites in NYC is Ferrara's, which calls itself a bakery.  One reason this is so is that in the US, most bakeries sell both bread and cake, and there is no need for a separate word for bread shop and pastry shop.

Comment: @StevenLittman: Are you telling me you've _never_ been to Financier? The one downtown? On Stone Street? Come on. You're pulling my leg.

Comment: @Ricky--No, I rarely find myself in that area.  And I never had the impression it was that famous.  Ferrara's, on the other hand, is an icon of Little Italy.

Comment: Understand that the vast majority of people in the US have never been to New York City.

Comment: @HotLicks Absolutely. The point about *pattisiers* in France is that every little town has them, not just places like Manhattan Island, and the West End of London.

Comment: @Ricky yes. Such places exist in very wealthy parts of London too - such as [this one](https://www.google.com/maps/uv?hl=en&pb=!1s0x48761ad1f1202085:0xd95daa3365ab315c!2m5!2m2!1i80!2i80!3m1!2i100!3m1!7e1!4s//plus.google.com/photos/photo/116814367583591976965/6081237461391770290!5spatisserie+des+reves,+marylebone+-+Google+Search&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBmuzL3tTKAhWEuBoKHTwyAIAQoioI8wIwMg). But my point is that in France every little town has them. The ones in London and New York are just an imitation of France. In London they mostly have French names, such as *Patisserie des Reves* - (dreams)

Comment: As has been suggested by the OP, in one of the comments below the question, *pastry chef* is likely to be understood to imply that the person works in a **restaurant** that serves complete meals (where there are also other kinds of chefs, responsible for other items on the menu). It may, therefore, not be a suitable word for somebody who runs a patisserie.